# How to filter data coming from socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have in the following example socket.io pushing data from my API on to the client side(every couple of seconds) and storing this data in state as an array of objects. This updates the view every time data is being emitted.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('options', data => {
    setOptions(options => [...data, ...options])
  })
}, [])
```

this works fine but now I want the option to filter this data by a [checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31gfA.png) image here  after it comes through socket on the client side. Here's an example of the data.

```
const OPTIONS = [
  {
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:21:00',
    ticker: 'SPY',
    description:
      'SPDR S&P 500 Option Alert: Fri $302 Puts Sweep (7) near the Ask: 500 @ $0.861 vs 11014 OI; Ref=$304.86',
  },
  {
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:21:01',
    ticker: 'AR',
    description:
      'Antero Resources Option Alert: Aug 21 $4 Calls Sweep (4) near the Bid: 350 @ $0.551 vs 2600 OI; Ref=$3.29',
  },
  {
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:20:57',
    ticker: 'NFLX',
    description:
      'Netflix Option Alert: Fri $400 Puts Sweep (3) below Bid!: 500 @ $0.327 vs 5115 OI; Earnings 7/15 After Close [est] Ref=$417.0',
  },
  {
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:21:21',
    ticker: 'SMH',
    description:
      'VanEck Vectors Semiconductor ETF Option Alert: Jul 17 $115 Puts Sweep (12) near the Ask: 645 @ $1.17 vs 3112 OI; Ref=$140.11',
  },
]
```

For example, if I check "Near the Ask" and "$1 or less" it will return

```
{
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:21:00',
    ticker: 'SPY',
    description:
      'SPDR S&P 500 Option Alert: Fri $302 Puts Sweep (7) near the Ask: 500 @ $0.861 vs 11014 OI; Ref=$304.86',
  },
```

and anything else that comes in socket emit that fit this criteria. but if I uncheck "below $1" and only have "Near the Ask" it will return

```
{
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:21:00',
    ticker: 'SPY',
    description:
      'SPDR S&P 500 Option Alert: Fri $302 Puts Sweep (7) near the Ask: 500 @ $0.861 vs 11014 OI; Ref=$304.86',
  },
{
    date: '2020-05-28',
    time: '19:21:00',
    ticker: 'SPY',
    description:
      'SPDR S&P 500 Option Alert: Fri $302 Puts Sweep (7) near the Ask: 500 @ $0.861 vs 11014 OI; Ref=$304.86',
  },
```

and anything that fit the criteria that comes from socket.

Here's the codebase for more reference

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

import styles from './Flow.module.scss'

import {FLOW_ROW_NAME} from './flow-data'

import {ENVIRONMENT} from '../../env'

import FlowList from './FlowList'

export default function Flow() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('')
  const socket = io(ENVIRONMENT.DATA_SERVER_URL)

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('all_options', function (data) {
      setOptions(options => [...options, ...data])
    })

    socket.on('options', data => {
      setOptions(options => _.uniqBy([...data, ...options], 'id'))
    })

    socket.on('clear', function () {
      setOptions([])
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={styles.flow_background_color}>
      <div className={styles.desktop_view}>
        <div className={styles.row_list}>
          {FLOW_ROW_NAME.map(data => {
            return (
              <div
                className={styles.row_name}
                style={{
                  paddingLeft: `${data.padding}rem`,
                }}
                key={data.name}
              >
                {data.name}
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className={styles.ul_list}>
            {options.map((data, index) => (
              <FlowList
                key={index}
                ticker={data.ticker}
                strike_price={data.strike_price}
                date_expiration={data.date_expiration}
                put_call={data.put_call}
                option_activity_type={data.option_activity_type}
                description={data.description}
                sentiment={data.sentiment}
                cost_basis={data.cost_basis}
                updated={data.updated}
                onClick={() => filterData(data.ticker)}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will make some performance issues to filter this on the front end given realtime flow on unlimited data I guess, but anyways here is my idea:

```
options.map((data, index) => ...)
```

should be:

```
options.filter(myFilterFunction).map((data, index) => ...)
```

The function itself should check for the selected filters (you should useState for them also) and thats how you will render only the filtered ones without dropping any data:

```
const myFilterFunction = (option) => {/*some if statements for the checked filters and option properties here*/}
```

And if you want to optimise the performance by consuming more memory with another array for the filtered options and a check if filters have been changed right after socket.on('options', data =>... and if filters are not changed you may want to filter just the new options.